# Webcam flickers in HP Pavilion C=S3300ng

Tags: drivers, hp, webcam

My HP Pavilion CS-3300ng has "Windows Hello" compatibility. For this, it has an infrared sensor attached to the webcam.

When I start using Microsoft Teams to make a video call, it starts flickering, black and white jittering images and the person on the other side hears a lot of drumbeat-like sounds.

That is so annoying. I tried to make cross-check on other laptops where Ubuntu is installed and without an infrared sensor. Microsoft teams perform well enough there. Is that a driver issue?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu have you installed? Add this info to your question by using the **edit** link below your question.